# is there a way to get a "subtree" from hclust ? (R)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I wish to create a "subtree" from an hclust object.

For example, let's say I have the following object:

```
a <- list()  # initialize empty object
a$merge <- matrix(c(-1, -2,
                    -3, -4,
                     1,  2,
             -5,-6,
             3,4), nc=2, byrow=TRUE ) 
a$height <- c(1, 1.5, 3,4,4.5)    # define merge heights
a$order <- 1:6              # order of leaves(trivial if hand-entered)
a$labels <- 1:6# LETTERS[1:4]    # labels of leaves
class(a) <- "hclust"        # make it an hclust object
plot(a)                     # look at the result
```

Now I wish the extract from it the following subtree:

```
a <- list()  # initialize empty object
a$merge <- matrix(c(-1, -2,
                    -3, -4,
                     1,  2
                ), nc=2, byrow=TRUE ) 
a$height <- c(1, 1.5, 3)    # define merge heights
a$order <- 1:4             # order of leaves(trivial if hand-entered)
a$labels <- 1:4# LETTERS[1:4]    # labels of leaves
class(a) <- "hclust"        # make it an hclust object
plot(a)                     # look at the result
```

How could I access it?

(I know that cutree could get me the objects of the sub tree, but not create an actual hclust object)

Thanks for any help,

Tal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but you could

```
a <- as.dendrogram(a)
branch1 <- a[[1]]
branch2 <- a[[2]]

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(a)
plot(branch1)
plot(branch2)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thanks nico.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the distance matrix, then you might do something similar to this:

```
subtree <- function(d, idx) {
  hclust(dist(d[idx, idx]))
}
d <- matrix(rnorm(50 * 50), 50)
s <- subtree(d, sample(1:50, 20))
plot(s)
```